# The type or namespace 'ZipFile' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, zip

I got the error "the type or namespace 'ZipFile' could not be found" when do

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
```

I've tried to using **System.IO** or **System.IO.Compression** as well as add reference **System.IO.Compression.ZipSystem**, but I still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the assembly System.IO.Compession.FileSystem in your project?

To use the ZipFile class, you must reference the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly in your project.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Just like you already tried before, you'll have to use the namespace `System.IO.Compression`.

```
using System.IO.Compression;
```

Another thing to mention is that the ZipFile-class does not implement the `IDisposable` interface. This is why you will need to replace ...

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
}
```

by ...

```
using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead("<insert path to zip-file here>"))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Lastly, as [Daantje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12181465/daantje) already pointed out, you'll have to make sure that your project has a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly.